# Collection count in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can I use `count($posts)` in Laravel to retrieve the number of elements in a collection, and how does it differ from `$posts->count()`?

Thank you

Comment: as far as I remember from the source code, $posts->count() actually use count(). will check.

Comment: `count()` is a PHP function for counting elements in a `Countable` (array, etc), while the `->count()` method is a `Collection.php` method that internally calls `count($this->items)`. In essence, there's no difference.

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Collections/Collection.php#L1368

Comment: It differs in that one is a collection method and the other is a method that takes the collection as an argument. It's different programming styles to achieve the same result but you need to choose the style that is consistent with the rest of your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>In short it depend of the Laravel version you're using.
on laravel 5.5 for example i see the [Collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html) class implement the [countable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) interface so you could call `count($posts)` but version 8 of laravel don't anymore implement it so you couldn't with this version.
Anyway you would get the same result using both function</s>

UPDATE: as mentionned by @apokryfos the `Collection` class implement `Enumerable` so there is no difference and you can use both.

Comment: Actually it still does implement countable indirectly by implementing [`Enumerable`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Collections/Enumerable.php)

Answer (score 2):

`->get()->count()` will load Eloquent model objects into memory and then will count those.

`->count()` will use DB aggregate function

simple php `count(Model::all())` will also count the model objects already loaded which is not necessary